# Confusion as to why the output of Module works in Map, the using the Module directly fails

Tags: replacement

I have some membership data as a list of {date, member numbers} pairs.

```
aprMembership = {
 {DateObject[{2015, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -5.`], 
    2524},
 {DateObject[{2016, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -5.`], 
   2592},
 {DateObject[{2017, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -5.`], 
   2619},
 {DateObject[{2018, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -5.`], 
   2574},
 {DateObject[{2019, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -5.`], 
   2625},
 {DateObject[{2020, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -5.`], 
   2532},
 {DateObject[{2021, 4, 1}, "Day", "Gregorian", -5.`], 2367}
}
```

I make a bar chart out of it and give the chart a symbol name, **membershipChart**

```
membershipChart =
 BarChart[aprMembership,
  ChartStyle -> {Cyan},
  LabelingFunction -> Above,
  ImageSize -> 400,
  BarSpacing -> None,
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {2000.0, 2700.0}},
  PlotRangePadding -> 0,
  Ticks -> {Automatic, Range[2000, 2700, 100]}
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I replace the head of memershipChart, Graphics, with graphicsHead and then extract the value and x-y coordinate of the text at the top.

```
Module[
 {
  graphics = membershipChart /. Graphics -> graphicsHead
  },
 Extract[graphics,
  Position[graphics, 
   Text[_, Offset[{0, 4}, {x_, y_}], ImageScaled[{0.5`, 0}]]]
  ]
 ]  

Text[\!\(\*"2524"\), Offset[{0, 4}, {2.1, 2524.}], 
  ImageScaled[{0.5, 0}]], 
 Text[\!\(\*"2592"\), Offset[{0, 4}, {4.3, 2592.}], 
  ImageScaled[{0.5, 0}]], 
 Text[\!\(\*"2619"\), Offset[{0, 4}, {6.5, 2619.}], 
  ImageScaled[{0.5, 0}]], 
 Text[\!\(\*"2574"\), Offset[{0, 4}, {8.7, 2574.}], 
   ImageScaled[{0.5, 0}]], 
 Text[\!\(\*"2625"\), Offset[{0, 4}, {10.9, 2625.}], 
  ImageScaled[{0.5, 0}]], 
 Text[\!\(\*"2532"\), Offset[{0, 4}, {13.1, 2532.}], 
  ImageScaled[{0.5, 0}]], 
 Text[\!\(\*"2367"\), Offset[{0, 4}, {15.3, 2367.}], 
      ImageScaled[{0.5, 0}]]}
```

I use the output as a list and extract the x-y as a simpler list using ReplaceAll

```
Map[
 # /. Text[i_Integer, Offset[{0, 4}, {x_Real, y_Real}], 
     ImageScaled[{0.5, 0}]] -> {x, y} &,
 {Text[2524, Offset[{0, 4}, {2.1`, 2524.`}], ImageScaled[{0.5`, 0}]], 
  Text[2592, Offset[{0, 4}, {4.3`, 2592.`}], ImageScaled[{0.5`, 0}]], 
  Text[2619, Offset[{0, 4}, {6.5`, 2619.`}], ImageScaled[{0.5`, 0}]], 
  Text[2574, Offset[{0, 4}, {8.7`, 2574.`}], ImageScaled[{0.5`, 0}]], 
  Text[2625, Offset[{0, 4}, {10.9`, 2625.`}], ImageScaled[{0.5`, 0}]],
  Text[2532, Offset[{0, 4}, {13.1`, 2532.`}], 
   ImageScaled[{0.5`, 0}]], 
  Text[2367, Offset[{0, 4}, {15.3`, 2368.`}], ImageScaled[{0.5`, 0}]]}
 ]

{{2.1, 2524.}, {4.3, 2592.}, {6.5, 2619.}, {8.7, 2574.}, {10.9, 
      2625.}, {13.1, 2532.}, {15.3, 2368.}}
```

This works fine. The puzzle and confusion I am experiencing is that when I use the Module in the Map code rather than the output of the Module, it doesn't work. I am at a loss to explain why.

```
 Map[
 # /. Text[i_Integer, Offset[{0, 4}, {x_Real, y_Real}], 
     ImageScaled[{0.5, 0}]] -> {x, y} &,
 Module[
  {
   graphics = membershipChart /. Graphics -> graphicsHead
   },
  Extract[graphics,
   Position[graphics, 
    Text[_, Offset[{0, 4}, {x_, y_}], ImageScaled[{0.5`, 0}]]]
   ]
  ]
 ]

{Text[\!\(\*"2524"\), Offset[{0, 4}, {2.1, 2524.}], 
  ImageScaled[{0.5, 0}]], 
 Text[\!\(\*"2592"\), Offset[{0, 4}, {4.3, 2592.}], 
  ImageScaled[{0.5, 0}]], 
 Text[\!\(\*"2619"\), Offset[{0, 4}, {6.5, 2619.}], 
  ImageScaled[{0.5, 0}]], 
 Text[\!\(\*"2574"\), Offset[{0, 4}, {8.7, 2574.}], 
  ImageScaled[{0.5, 0}]], 
 Text[\!\(\*"2625"\), Offset[{0, 4}, {10.9, 2625.}], 
  ImageScaled[{0.5, 0}]], 
 Text[\!\(\*"2532"\), Offset[{0, 4}, {13.1, 2532.}], 
  ImageScaled[{0.5, 0}]], 
 Text[\!\(\*"2367"\), Offset[{0, 4}, {15.3, 2367.}], 
  ImageScaled[{0.5, 0}]]}
```

Comment: It's _right_ there in the output. You're matching on `Text[i_Integer, ...]` but the output _directly_ is actually wrapped with `Style`. When you copy paste, Mathematica is converting those style specs to integers. It's easy to find this if you hit it with `FullForm`. Turn `Text[i_Integer, ...]` into `Text[i_Style, ...]` and all will be fine. The `Text[\!\(\*"2524"\), ...]` should have given this away.

Comment: So the question is, why when I copy and paste `Text[i_Style,...`' does it become `Text[i_Integer, ...` On my screen they look identical but I think you have found the root problem.

Comment: Yes. Mathematica strips most `Style` specs when converting from `OutputForm` to `InputForm` unless the user adds them explicitly. In general, you can't expect something that only _looks_ like an integer to be an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by b3m2a1 in the comment, when you copy the output from the graphic and paste it, the pasted copy has the `Style` wrapper removed.

I didn't see it because I was only looking at my screen where they appeared identical.

The solution to go directly from the graphic to the desired output is to replace `Integer` with a `Blank`

```
Map[
 # /.Text[_, Offset[{0, 4}, {x_Real, y_Real}], ImageScaled[{0.5, 0}]] -> {x, y} &,
 Extract[membershipChart,
  Position[membershipChart, 
   Text[_, Offset[{0, 4}, {x_, y_}], ImageScaled[{0.5`, 0}]]]
  ]
 ]
```